# .htaccess redirect if search word has some string before it

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need help with creating some `.htaccess` rules. Currently I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On

Redirect 404 /favicon.ico

#Check if request was made for RSS feed
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/events($|/) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/tickers($|/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ rss.php/?$1 [L]
```

What I need:

- if URL is like: domain.com/events/, don't redirect
- if URL is like: domain.com/[anything]/events/, do internal redirect
- `events` can be also `tickers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of querying `REQUEST_URI`, this should be handled in the `RewriteRule` itself. It is actually a fairly simple pattern to match, and is recommended to use `[^/]+` to capture all characters up to the first `/` into `$1`.  If that group is not present, the rewrite will not take place.  To allow either `events` or `tickers` after the first `/`, use `(events|tickers)`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(events|tickers) rss.php/?$1 [L,NC]
```

It isn't necessary to match the `$` or trailing slash since you are not using them in the rewritten URL. If you *do* need to match it, such that you don't rewrite when the URL is `/something/events/somethingelse`, just use `/?$` for an optional trailing slash and the end of the string.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(events|tickers)/?$ rss.php/?$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: With a little modification (I forgot to mention that I needed also to capture the `events|tickers`), your solution worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding a condition at the end to rewrite /events/ to /events/ and see if it will override the previous match.